# Is there any CLI alternative to xdiskusage?

Tags: raspbmc

I really like to use `xdiskusage` on Ubuntu. It shows the disk usage of my files and folders in a handy way.

I've got Raspbmc installed on my Raspberry Pi, which doesn't have a X server. Thus, I cannot use `xdiskusage` on it. Is there any good CLI alternative to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do this: `ncdu`.

SSH into the Raspberry Pi,  then run the command `ncdu /` . This will show the disk usage in a xdiskusage way. You can navigate with your keyboard just like in `xdiskusage`.

By the way, I found that it's still possible to use `xdiskusage` without an X server on the Pi: `ssh pi@<IP> 'cd /; du -k' | xdiskusage`

Answer (score 3):

The `du` (diskusage) command is what you want.

`du /` Will show you the usage of every directory measured in blocks.

`du --max-depth=1 -k /` Will show the usage for the top level directories measured in Kb.

My favorite usage is:
`du --max-depth=1 / |sort -n`

By piping the output to sort -n it will sort the list from least use to most.

Replace `/` in the examples with the top level directory you want to check.